# Jest not updating in react and conflicting with jest in my node,js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, package.json

My app is not running I am getting a very long error - below is a a summary (the full error is at the bottom). If I remove jest from node.js the error goes and my app runs (but obviously jest doesn't work on my server then).

```
...The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "^24.9.0"...
```

On looking at the react app I see that the versions of babel are old. I also created a brand new react app using create-react-app and can see when I do that the babel-jest (and many of the jest files) are around the 26 version number.

### babel-jest version numbers

| my React App | my node.js server | a new app using create-react-app |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24.9.0 | 26.6.0 | 26.6.0 |

### It looks like my error is because the versions of jest in create react app are out of date causing the problem.

How do I fix this? How do I update the packages in create-react-app?
I thought they updated when I re-ran npm init??

### What I have tried

I have deleted node_modeuls and package.json.lock and re-installed and it is the same

### SETUP FILES

My setup
my folder structure looks like this

```
./
./client  (react client app)
./client/package.json
./client/node_modules
package.json
node.modules
./server   (node.js api app)
./server/package.json
my jest is running from the ./package.json file.
```

## code setup

### ./package.json

```
{
    "name": "Infoshot",
    "version": "0.0.4",
    "description": "Research Tool",
    "main": "cd ./server && server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "cd ./server && node server.js",
        "server": "cd ./server && nodemon server.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix ./client/",
        "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run client\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd ./client && NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install  && CI= npm run build",
        "compile-saas": "node-sass ./client/src/scss/a_main.scss ./server/nodeClient/public/css/main.css -w",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "./node_modules"
        ]
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "config": "^3.2.2",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "ejs": "^3.1.5",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
        "ijavascript": "^5.2.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.7.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
        "nodemailer-sendgrid": "^1.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
    }
}
```

### delete.test.json

```
describe.only('DELETE TEST: getDocument', () => {
    test('Say Hi', async () => {
        const bum = 'bum';
        expect(bum).toBe(bum);
    });
});
```

## ./client/package.json

As I said earlier I don't think this is relavant as it is not be run as I am running jest from ./server with npm run jest:watch

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "config": "^3.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "previewProd": "react-scripts build && serve"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/components/documentEditor/*.js",
      "<rootDir>/server/",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "!<rootDir>/src/index.js",
      "!<rootDir>/src/registerServiceWorker.js"
    ]
```

### Full Error Message

```
^C


[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                     
[0] npm ERR! errno 130
[0] npm ERR! Infoshot@0.0.4 server: `cd ./server && nodemon server.js`
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 130
[0] npm ERR! 
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the Infoshot@0.0.4 server script.
[0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0] npm run server exited with code SIGINT
 ✘ bob@TDI-MacBook-Air  ~/Documents/repoActive/infoshot   develop  npm run dev

> Infoshot@0.0.4 dev /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot
> concurrently "npm run server"  "npm run client"

[0] 
[0] > Infoshot@0.0.4 server /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot
[0] > cd ./server && nodemon server.js
[0] 

> Infoshot@0.0.4 client /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot
> npm start --prefix ./client/

[0] [nodemon] 1.19.4
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`

> client@0.1.0 start /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot/client
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "^24.9.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 26.6.3) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/bob/Documents/repoActive/infoshot/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bob/.npm/_logs/2020-12-08T08_43_14_491Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Infoshot@0.0.4 client: `npm start --prefix ./client/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Infoshot@0.0.4 client script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bob/.npm/_logs/2020-12-08T08_43_14_528Z-debug.log
npm run client exited with code 1
[0] -------------------------------
[0] Server started on Port: 5000
[0] (node:90252) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
[0] MongoDb Connected .......
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out

I needed to remove jest from ./ installation (the server installation) and then install the older version of jest so it matched the react version

```
npm install angular@6.2.1
```